# Escape Character in web.config transform

Tags: .net, xml, web-config

I have a portion of XML in Web.QA.config that looks like this:

```
<net>
  <encryption>
    <add key="EncKey" value="stuff>stuff" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </encryption>
</net>
```

But when I run it through the transform, the > gets escaped and the output is:

```
<net>
  <encryption>
    <add key="EncKey" value="stuff&gt;stuff" />
  </encryption>
</net>
```

Is there something I can change such that the > will not be escaped?  I'm adding transforms into a legacy application and that is the way the application is expecting the EncKey string.

Thanks.

Comment: They aren't parsing it with a real XML parser? Ouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MSBuild from the command line, you can add the parameter:

> /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False